# Unable to communicate with SIM800 board on raspberry pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi4, sim800

I have connected a new [Itead sim800 board](https://www.itead.cc/raspberry-pi-sim800-gsm-gprs-add-on-v2-0.html) to a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B and trying to handle incoming SMS.
I have disabled the serial login shell using the [link](https://learnaddict.com/2018/02/17/send-and-receive-sms-text-messages-with-raspberry-pi-and-sim800-gsm-board/) and tried gammu and minicom(with /dev/ttyAMA0, /dev/serial0 & /dev/serial1 on baud rate 9600).

But the board doesn't seem to be responding.
Following is the result of gammu.

```
pi@tpk:~ $ sudo gammu getallsms 
No response in specified timeout. Probably the phone is not connected.
pi@tpk:~ $
```

Following is the result of minicom:

```
pi@tpk:~ $ sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyAMA0 -b 9600
Welcome to minicom 2.7.1

OPTIONS: I18n 
Compiled on Aug 13 2017, 15:25:34.
Port /dev/ttyAMA0, 04:46:20

Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys
```

and the console hangs without accepting any characters.  The status line at the bottom shows that it's offline.

Following is the snap of the boards connected.
[sim800 board on raspberry pi 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNz0O.jpg)